# Nest API humidity % round to nearest 5%?

Tags: nest-api

using Nest API v1.1, it seems that humidity % are round to the nearest 5%. e.g a level of 49% humidity becomes 50%, 53% -> 55%, etc..

I wonder why this would be. anyone who has the same results?

Comment: Yes, sadly I see the same behaviour as this. I suspect it's a deliberate limitation of the data provided by the API.

Answer (score 1):

Humidistats are generally only accurate to 3-7% RH, so it would make sense to round the output to prevent developers from building logic around smaller changes.

Nest doesn't publish the accuracy rating of their humidity sensor though.